# Intermittent 462 Error when Using Word

Tags: vba, excel

I have the most baffling set of errors cropping up in my code.  The goal is just to create a Word document from a template, and edit the document using find/replace to fill in some data from excel.  Here are the symptoms:

- When I run the code the first time, everything works perfectly
- The next time I run the code, one of two thing happens depending on what I did before calling it:

  - If I closed the word document before running the code again, the second time I run it (and every even-numbered run after that) it fails.  This happens even if I've closed the userform and reran the code from the VBA editor.  I think this has something to do with binding the word objects, but I'm new to VBA and don't see what I've done wrong.
  - If I didn't close the word document and just press the button again, the code runs and it spawns a new document, but that must not be set to the active document because it just edits the first document I spawned again.

This is the offending code:

```
Private Sub Generate_Click()
Set wordApp = New Word.Application
wordApp.Visible = True
wordApp.Documents.Add Template:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Template.dotx"

FindReplace "[[[DATE_TAG]]]", DateBox.Value
FindReplace "[[[SHIPPING_TAG]]]", POBox.Value
' ... and more of that ...

Set wordApp = Nothing
End Sub

Sub FindReplace(find As String, replace As String)
With Word.ActiveDocument.Range.find ' <---- This line is where the debugger points
                                    '       on the 462 error
    .Text = find
    .Replacement.Text = replace
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .MatchCase = True
    .MatchWholeWord = True
    .Forward = True
    .Execute replace:=wdReplaceAll

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `With Word.ActiveDocument.Range.find` - what is `Word` here?  Do you have a global variable set up which maintains the reference to `wordApp` created in the calling sub?

Comment: Word here is a reference to the Word application, because this code is being written in Excel.  If I don't qualify it like that (ie just `ActiveDocument.Range.Find`), I get exactly the same set of errors as I do with it qualified.  I figured it's better to be on the explicit side.

Comment: To answer the second part of your question, no.  If I try to do `Dim wordApp as Application` outside of any sub, I get a type mismatch error on running the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Generate_Click` you create an instance of Word referenced by the variable `wordApp`, but that variable isn't included in the scope of the called Sub `FindReplace`.

To resolve this you have options:

1. Create a global variable to reference the Word instance (which would also be accessible to FindReplace) or
2. Pass an additional parameter to `FindReplace` via which it can use that Word instance without requiring a Global variable.

Try this instead:

```
Private Sub Generate_Click()
    Dim wdDoc as Word.Document, wordApp As Word.Application
    Set wordApp = New Word.Application
    wordApp.Visible = True
    Set wdDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add(Template:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Template.dotx")

    FindReplace wdDoc, "[[[DATE_TAG]]]", DateBox.Value
    FindReplace wdDoc, "[[[SHIPPING_TAG]]]", POBox.Value
    ' ... and more of that ...

Set wordApp = Nothing
End Sub

Sub FindReplace(wdDoc as Word.Document, find As String, replace As String)
    With wdDoc.Range.find 
    .Text = find
    .Replacement.Text = replace
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .MatchCase = True
    .MatchWholeWord = True
    .Forward = True
    .Execute replace:=wdReplaceAll

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you!  That worked perfectly, and your answer was well explained, so I can hopefully avoid this type of error in the future.